# How to set a bold Text by using getString()

Tags: android, textview, settext, getstring

I want to show a BOLD text by setText() , but i just saw a text is not BOLD :( How can I solve this problem ?

Here my code : 
String.xml :

```
<string name="country"><b>AMERICA-default</b></string>
```

my Java code :

```
Resources resources;
TextView tvCountry;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("test","onCreate()-second Activity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    resources = getResources();
    tvCountry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
    tvCountry.setText(resources.getString(R.string.country));//its not working !Text is not bold!
    //CANNOT USE : tvCountry.setText(R.string.country);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Replace < with &lt; country value

<string name="country">&lt;b>AMERICA-default&lt;/b></string>
```

Set resource string using Html.fromHtml() which support html tag.

```
tvCountry.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.country)));
```

Comment: great ! i tried and my text was bold :) thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Typeface` class :

```
tvCountry.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it on Xml file where u creatd textview

```
android:textStyle="bold"
```

Comment: its ok but i have to use setText(getResources().getString(R.string.country));